# How come we can treat space as a blackbody?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

I thought that the condition to be a black body was that an object had to absorb all incident radiation without reflecting any.

My understanding is, electrons in atoms absorb the incoming radiation. Empty space which is a vacuum shouldn't have many electrons that absorb radiation and so how does one treat empty space as a black body.

I am asking this because I read in my astrophysics notes it says that CMB radiation from space describes a black body spectrum.

Comment: CMB radiation $\neq$ space.

Comment: The CMB radiation we see was originally produced by a dense, opaque plasma (the state of the universe 13.7 billion years ago). When the plasma recombined and became transparent, the existing blackbody photons traveled on through the now-transparent universe as it expanded. Although the expansion of space redshifted the photons, it preserved the overall blackbody spectrum of all the CMB photons.

Comment: Contextually yes.